# Jquery Select alternative in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How would I do this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
     scope.canvas = $(element[0]).children()[0]
}
```

In pure AngularJS? I only have one canvas (along with some other elements) in the directive, and I just need to set a variable equal to the canvas so I can manipulate it with an API later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular.element might be what you're looking for: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.canvas = angular.element(element[0]).children()[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has it's own implementation of subset of jQuery called JQlite: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Alternatively, you can just use native DOM selection.